# parsing, getting JSON, swift

Tags: json, swift, alamofire

I have problem getting Json with a generic function. I attached the code below. the problem in line " guard let JsonResponse = try? response.result.value". it does not work. gives me "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context"
this is the code:

```
class ServicesManager<T: TargetType>  {
    func fetchingData<M: Decodable>(target: T, response: M.Type, completion: @escaping (Result<(M?, NSError)>?) -> Void) {
        let method = Alamofire.HTTPMethod(rawValue: target.method.rawValue)
        let parameters = buildParameters(task: target.task)
        Alamofire.request(target.domian + target.path, method: method!,
                          // .0  realting to parameters and the .1 for the ecndoding
                          parameters: parameters.0, encoding: parameters.1).responseJSON { (response) in
            //fetching the result and encoding it and return it in the completion
            guard let statusCode = response.response?.statusCode else {
                // Add Custom Error
                completion(.failure(NSError()))
                return
            }

            if statusCode == 200 {
                // Successful request
                guard let JsonResponse = try? response.result.value else {
                    // Add Custom Error in case failed getting the JSONResponse
                    completion(.failure(NSError()))
                    return
              }
               guard let JsonData = try?.JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: JsonResponse, options: []) else {
                   // Add Custom Error
                   completion(.failure(NSError()))
                   return
               }
                // M: means decoadable
                guard let responseObject = try?.JSONDecoder.decode(M.self, from: JsonData) else {
                  // Add Custom Error
                    completion(.failure(NSError()))
                    return
             }
               // decode the result and send it back to the user
               DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completion(.success(responseObject))
               }
           }

           else {
                // again Add custom error based on the statusCode such as 404
               completion(.failure(NSError()))
            }
        }
        
    }
    //MARK: -create the parameters method
    private func buildParameters(task: Task) -> ([String: Any], ParameterEncoding){
        switch task {
        case .requestPlain:
            return ([:], URLEncoding.default) // no parameters, URLEncoding(Json, query..)
        case .requestParameters(parameters: let parameters, encoding: let encoding):
            return (parameters, encoding) // giv it parameter ,encoding such as JSON
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to get the result.

Comment: You should not use `responseJSON` anymore in favor of `responseDecodable`. And never `try?` in a Codable context. Catch the error and return it rather than meaningless *unswifty* empty `NSError`

Comment: The error occurs because `response` does not throw and `response.result` doesn't have a `value` property. Remove the `try?` to see the real error. And you should get also an error about the wrong usage of `Result`. Apart from that the goal of `Result` is to get rid of the optionals.

Comment: In addition this `try?.JSONSerialization` and this `try?.JSONDecoder` are invalid syntax. And with `JSONDecoder` you have to create an instance. You can´t call `decode` on the type.

Comment: You are using `responseJSON` which is deprecated, so you are doing internally JSONSerialization:  Data -> "JSON" (Dictionary/Array/String), then, you are calling again JSONSerialization to do JSON -> Data, and then JSONDecoder to do Data -> Model. A lot of extra work... Use directly `.responseDecodable()`.

Comment: Thank you all your comments benefit me. I fixed the problem. I replace the code with catching the error and return it and I used directly .responseDecodable()